# How to export a function, from tmux.conf

Tags: git, bash, prompt, tmux

I wrote an addon for tmux, [tmux-gitbar](https://github.com/aurelien-rainone/tmux-gitbar). It shows some information about Git status of current directory in tmux status bar. The status bar must be **updated each time the user runs a command**, to do this I added a function, called from the`$PROMPT_COMMAND`variable.

### What I'm doing for now:

#### in file **`.bashrc`:**

```
source ~/.tmux-gitbar/tmux-gitbar.sh;
```

#### in file **`tmux-gitbar.sh`:**

```
update_gitbar() {
    #
    # update tmux status bar
    #
}
PROMPT_COMMAND="update_gitbar; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

I'd like to achieve the same result **without adding a line to `.bashrc`**. All should be performed in`tmux.conf`file. I already managed to modify `$PROMPT_COMMAND` by doing this in `tmux.conf`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="update_gitbar; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

**Now my problem is to export `update_gitbar` function into the environment**

I tried various ways to source the script, but with no luck:

```
run-shell "source ~/.tmux-gitbar/tmux-gitbar.sh"
run-shell "eval $(~/.tmux-gitbar/tmux-gitbar.sh)"
run-shell "eval $(cat ~/.tmux-gitbar/tmux-gitbar.sh)"
```

I always get :

```
update_gitbar: command not found
```

### Question:

How can I, **from tmux.conf file**, export a function (declared in another file) and make that function available to the environment?

If that can help, current code is available on [github](https://github.com/aurelien-rainone/tmux-gitbar)

Comment: Did you try to add `export -f update_gitbar` at end of `tmux-gitbar.sh`?

Comment: @F.Hauri Yes I did. If I do `run-shell tmux-gitbar.sh`, also exported variables are not available in the new tmux session. So also functions exported with `-f` arent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying to solve it via run-shell is futile. By definition, anything run using run-shell is in a sub-shell/child process, and will not be able to affect tmux's environment.

#### External shell script

Honestly, I highly recommend that you use an external shell script, instead of a function. Among other things, this will allow you to make changes to `update_gitbar` that take effect instantly everywhere. It's slightly less efficient, of course, but I don't think you're likely to notice the difference. Just throw it in `~/bin`, say, and make `PROMPT_COMMAND` be `"$HOME/bin/update_gitbar; $PROMPT_COMMAND"`.

However, if you must insist on using shell functions – which I must point out, are a bash-*only* feature, and was also the source of *major* security vulnerabilities last year ("ShellShock"; note: not the *use* of the feature, just its actual *existence*, and very broken implementation, which has since been fixed in newer versions), there are two solutions I can offer.

#### Export before running tmux

The first, and simplest way, is just to make sure you do the export in the environment that starts the tmux session, and not after or within it. If you start tmux versus a shell script, say, you'd just do:

```
export -f update_gitbar
tmux
```

As part of that startup, you'd also probably want to put the definition of `update_gitbar`, and your `PROMPT_COMMAND` setting. Note that once tmux is started, you wouldn't be able to change `update_gitbar` and have it propagate to everywhere it's being used – that's why I recommended a shell script instead. You would however still be able to modify its meaning for *new* shells (in new tmux panes, say) using the method described below.

#### Unportable variable exports

The final method, the hardest and least-portable, is to use tmux's `setenv`, or the same `VAR=value` syntax in `.tmux.conf`. Bash implements its unique "export function" feature just by using a normal export variable, with a special format.

The exact nature of that format is different between different distributions and versions of bash, due to fixing the "ShellShock" security vulnerabilities mentioned above, so (a) what you do in one environment may not work in another, and (b) I can't tell you the exact exported variable name you need to do what you want.

In order to find out what variable format you need, in a regular shell that has `update_gitbar`, run:

```
env | sed -n '/^[^=]*update_gitbar/,/^}/p' |
perl -ne 'chomp; $a .= $a? "; $_" : $_; END{$a=~s/=(.*)/='\''$1'\''/; print "$a\n"}'
```

That complicated command just looks in the environment for the exported shell function and prints its value. Bash includes newlines in the value of the exported variable, so it continues grabbing from the environment until it sees a single line with a closing brace alone. Then it replaces all those newlines with semicolons so that you can put it all on one line. Finally, it replaces the value of the variable inside single quotes, to avoid special meanings of characters. If you have trouble getting a usable value from that command for some reason, you could do that process yourself.

For me, with an example like below illustrates the format on my particular distribution and bash version (notice in the command I changed `update_gitbar` to `hello`). As I mentioned, *your results may vary*, so be sure to try it out on your system.

After you get the variable you want, just plug it into your `.tmux.conf`, or use the `setenv` version.

```
hello() {
    echo hi;
}
export -f hello
hello
>>>> hi
env | sed -n '/^[^=]*hello/,/^}/p' |
perl -ne 'chomp; $a .= $a? "; $_" : $_; END{$a=~s/=(.*)/='\''$1'\''/; print "$a\n"}'
>>>> BASH_FUNC_hello%%='() {  echo hi\!; }'
```

(The `>>>>`-prefixed lines are output, not part of the script in the example.)

Comment: Mikah, thanks a lot for this very detailed answer. I learned a couple things thanks to you. I will go for the external script solution. Don't know what I didn't think about that myself, as when I read you, it seems so obvious.

Comment: And I was forgetting...Welcome to StackOverflow ;-)

Answer (score 2):

*tmux*'s `set-environment` looks promising and might be of help to you.
Let me quote the relevant section from `man tmux`:

> ```
> set-environment [-gru] [-t target-session] name [value]
>               (alias: setenv)
>         Set or unset an environment variable.
>         If -g is used, the change is made in the global environment; 
>         otherwise, it is applied to the session environment for target-session.
>         The -u flag unsets a variable.
>         -r indicates the variable is to be removed from the environment before starting a new process.
> ```

You might want to use `set-environment -g PROMPT_COMMAND update_gitbar` as an instruction inside your *tmux-gitbar.conf* which will be sourced from *.tmux.conf* via `source /path/to/tmux-gitbar.conf`

**EDIT:**
Forgot to mention that `update_gitbar` should be an exectuable file somewhere in `PATH`.

P.S.

Cool plugin! :-)

Comment: thanks :-).  I know about `set-environment`.But my problem is not to modify PROMPT_COMMAND,  I managed to do it from tmux.conf by simply  declaring it. My problem is how to export `update_gitbar`

Comment: Why not store `update_gitbar` as an executable somewhere in `PATH`, say in */usr/bin*, and then simply `set-environment -g PROMPT_COMMAND update_gitbar` ? Am I missing something ? I think [Powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline) does that with its `POWERLINE_COMMAND` variable.

Comment: The solution i found now is to simply source the script with the update_guitar function in bashrc. I'd prefer to remove this requirement to ease the installation as I plan to make my plugin installable automatically by [tmux plugin manager](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm)

Answer (score 1):

Whereas I have to point out that there are already viable answers, I want to mention one more solution to your problem.

There's a mod adding full-fledged scripting to tmux: http://ershov.github.io/tmux/ (I'm the author).

It not only allows to create new commands:

```
proc update_gitbar {} { run-shell "source ~/.tmux-gitbar/tmux-gitbar.sh" }
```

(for your case)

... but also allows you to bind several actions to 'mode' keystrokes.

It's also usable for writing complete plugins in that language without a need to spawn a shell at all.